# Creating a timer for powerups in a game loop?

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to add a timer to my power up in the game. In space invaders, when the core hits 500 I added it so that you gain an extra gun, but this is infinite and I only want to it to go for ten seconds. I tried the threading library which didn't work for e with object oriented programming, any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would really help to see what you tried and what didn't work. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? What module do you use - PyGame, PgZero, Arcade, Pyglet, other? You should get current time and set `powerup_end = current_time + 10seconds` and in every loop get `current time` and compare it with `powerup_end`  - like `if current time >= powerup_end: ... finish power up .... else  ... display (powerup_end - current time)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import time

time_in_seconds = 10

def countdown(t):
    
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1    

countdown(time_in_seconds)
```

for more details, check out this [LINK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-python/)